# single responsibility for Order Model or ProductService?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

For single responsibility concern, should I pass the ProductService to the Order `model` class or   `addProducts` method? Or how it should it be done?

When adding a new product to an Order, it require to fetch product information via `ProductService` class

`addProducts` method will take responsibility to check if Products is already exist in the database, it will update the Qty if exist or otherwise, it will fetch product information from `ProductService` class and then add Product information in the database.

Usage:

```
const Order = new OrderModel(request.OrderId); 

// Update Qty on existing products in Db or Add New Products in db
Order.addProducts([
    { ProductId: 111, Qty: 1 }, // new item 
    { ProductId: 222, Qty: 2 }  // existing item, set from 1 to 2 Qty in db
])


class ProductService {
    getProduct(productId) {
       return {} //fetch product info via API
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every method call that you make on an `Order` instance is going to depend on the same `ProductService` instance, so it makes sense to pass the `ProductService` as an argument to the constructor rather than as an argument of the `addProducts` method.

If the `ProductService` is universal, meaning that all individual `Order` instances share the same `ProductService` instance, then you can use a helper function to create an `Order`.  In whatever root file you instantiate your `ProductService`, you can export some factory function which has knowledge of that instance.

```
export const service = new ProductService();
export const createOrder = (orderId) => new Order(service, orderId);
```

That way the `Order` class is still decoupled from the `ProductService` class.